# When run on my phone, the send button still does nothing?

Tags: android, bundle, oncreate

I am using the tutorial of creating MyFirstApp. I have got up to a point where I have followed all the tutorials and have struck a point where it doesn't work. The tutorial says "You can now run the app. When it opens, type a message in the text field, click Send, and the message appears on the second activity." but it will not work on my device, the send button does nothing other than turn blue all the time it is being pressed. My code for this point, for the onCreate(Bundle) is:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Get the message from the intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    // Create the text view
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);

    // Set the text view as the activity layout
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

    // Make sure we're running on Honeycomb or higher to use ActionBar APIs
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Also, my activity_main.xml :

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send"
    android:onClick="sendMessage" />
```

and my MainActivity.java part :

```
/** Called when the user clicks the send button */
public void sendMessage (View view) {
    // Do something in response to button
    Intent intent = new Intent (this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
}
```

Comment: Can we see the code for the onClick?

Comment: @Jbad26 sure, I've edited the question to contain parts from other files. I hope I've added the relevant parts.

Comment: That is very helpful did my solution work or are you still having trouble?

Answer (score 1):

sorry about the response time I was away from my computer for the weekend.  That being said you are missing this line at the end of your sendMessage function:

```
startActivity(intent);
```

This tells the activity to be started with the intent you created. Right now you are creating an intent but not sending it anywhere.  Hope that helps.